# key is not sorted in JSON array using javascript

Tags: javascript

In this I am trying to sort the data by `partNo` and it is perfectly sorted with this, but my problem is that **the first column of the table does not sort with the rest of the columns**.  `sr No` has to be sorted with all other columns

here `sr No` is a key which is not sorted with other columns

```js
let productDetails = {
        "10": [{
            id: "1",
            partNo: "100",
            productName: "bag",
            size: "30",
            color: ["Blue"],
            description: "sky bags ",
        }],
        "20": [{
            id: "2",
            partNo: "15",
            productName: "bottle",
            size: "10",
            color: ["Green", "Orange"],
            description: "plastic and still",
        }]
        ,
        "30": [{
            id: "4",
            partNo: "25",
            productName: "lunchbox",
            size: "20",
            color: ["Blue", "Red"],
            description: "fresh food",
        }],
        "40": [{
            id: "3",
            partNo: "45",
            productName: "pen",
            size: "10",
            color: ["Red", "Blue"],
            description: "gel pen ",
        }]
    };
    /**
     * This function displays the data in the table
     */
    function displayData() {
        objectArray = Object.values(productDetails);
        display(objectArray);
    }
    
    function display(productStore) {
        messageTable(" ");
        let table = "<table border = 1 cellpadding = 10 ><th colspan=7 >Product Details</th><tr><th>sr No</th><th>Product Id</th><th>Part No</th><th>Name</th><th>Size</th><th>Color</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
        for (var key in productDetails) {
            for (var weight in productDetails[key]) {
                
                table += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td>";
                table += "<td>" + productDetails[key][weight].id + "</td>";
                table += "<td>" + productDetails[key][weight].partNo + "</td>";
                table += "<td>" + productDetails[key][weight].productName + "</td>";
                table += "<td>" + productDetails[key][weight].size + "</td>";
                table += "<td>" + productDetails[key][weight].color + "</td>";
                table += "<td>" + productDetails[key][weight].description + "</td>";                   
    
    
            }
        } messageTable(table);
    
    }
    
   
    
    /**
     * function to sort an array by part No
    */
    function sortByPartNo() {
        let arr = [];
        item = Object.keys(productDetails)
        console.log(item)
        item.forEach(function (index) {
            productDetails[index].forEach(function (indexA) {
                arr.push(indexA);
            });
        })
        arr.sort(function (first, second) {
            return parseFloat(first.partNo) - parseFloat(second.partNo);
        });
        console.log(arr)
        printArray(arr, item)
    
    }

     /**
     * function to print array in the table
     */
    function printArray(arr, item) {
        messageTable(" ");
        let table = "<table border = 1 cellpadding = 10 ><th colspan=7 >Product Details</th><tr><th>sr No</th><th>Product Id</th><th>Part No</th><th>Name</th><th>Size</th><th>Color</th><th>Description</th></tr>";
        for (let key in arr) {

            table += "<tr><td>" + item[key] + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + arr[key].id + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + arr[key].partNo + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + arr[key].productName + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + arr[key].size + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + arr[key].color + "</td>";
            table += "<td>" + arr[key].description + "</td>";
            
        } messageTable(table);
    }
   /**
     * function is to print the table
    */
    function messageTable(data) {
        document.getElementById("messageTableA").innerHTML = data;
    }
    
    /**
     * this function is to print the message
     */
    function message(message) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = message;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
       
    
     <style>
        th,
        td,
        p,
        input {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: solid 1px #DDD;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        th {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>      

       
</head>

<body onload="displayData()">
        <h2>Product Details:</h2>
        <form action="">

                <input type="button" value="sortByPartNo" onclick="sortByPartNo();">&nbsp;

                <p id="result"></p>
                <p id="demo"></p>
                <p id="messageTableA"></p>

            </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @pwilcox as you know the previous question is closed due to some people didn't read carefully the question , if you know the answer plz let me know

Comment: `productDetails` is a JavaScript Object Literal, it is not JSON. [What is JSON anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Comment: yeah it's my mistake sorry i 'll correct this @RandyCasburn

Comment: What exactly do you think having separate sort functions (one for `Object.values(productDetails);` and one for `Object.keys(productDetails);` would produce? it should be clear that if you are sorting them separately, they will, well, be sorted separately (differently at different times). Your data structure should change so that each record contains the `sr No` - the keys are then irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple ways to go about this, but the simplest would be to just construct a new objects from the original one that contains both the keys and values.

i.e. turn this:

```
{
  "10": [{
    "partNo": "100",
    "size": "30",
    // etc
  }],
  // ...
}
```

into this

```
[
  {
    "key": "10",
    "partNo": "100",
    "size": "30",
    // etc
  },
  // ...
]
```

or alternatively, something like this works too. A similar approach is used in the concrete code example below.

```
[
  {
    "key": "10",
    "value": {
      "partNo": "100",
      "size": "30",
      // etc
    },
  },
  // ...
]
```

Basically, we just need to bundle all the related information together before we do a sort(). After we sort, we can pass the bundled data as-is to your display functions, or we can separate them back into two lists, however you prefer.

A practical simplified example:

```js
const data = {
  1: {
    color: 'blue',
    size: 10,
  },
  2: {
    color: 'green',
    size: 50,
  },
  3: {
    color: 'yellow',
    size: 5,
  },
}

// Object.entries() will reshape the data in a way that keeps keys and values together
// then we .sort() based on size
const sorted = (
  Object.entries(data)
  .sort((x, y) => x[1].size - y[1].size)
)
console.log('sorted keys and values', sorted)

// If you want, you can then split them back out into two separate array, like you had it:
console.log('sorted keys', sorted.map(x => x[0]))
console.log('sorted values', sorted.map(x => x[1]))
```

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to learn about Object.entries, used in this particular example.

Answer (score 2):

Scotty Jamison responded first and gave you a good description of options and alternatives.  I urge you to accept his answer.

However, I figured I minus well provide my work that I had developed in response to your original question incorrectly marked as a duplicate (as you mention in the comments to your question here).  It is a more fully worked out version of Scotty's first proposal, which places the outer key as a property inside the array entry.

```js
// Just a convenience for building productDetails
let pdVal = (id,no,name,size,colors,desc) => ({
  id: id,
  partNo: no,
  productName: name,
  size: size,
  color: colors,
  description: desc      
})

let productDetails = {
  "10": [pdVal("1","100","bag","30",["Blue"],"sky bags ")],
  "20": [pdVal("2","15","bottle","10",["Green", "Orange"],"plastic and still")],
  "30": [pdVal("4","25","lunchbox","20",["Blue", "Red"],"fresh food")],
  "40": [pdVal("3","45","pen","10",["Red", "Blue"],"gel pen ")]
};

function sortByPartNo() {

  let arr = [];
  for (let key of Object.keys(productDetails)) {
    let obj = productDetails[key][0];
    arr.push(Object.assign({}, obj, {key}));
  }
  arr.sort((a,b) => parseFloat(a.partNo) - parseFloat(b.partNo))
  printArray(arr);

}

function printArray(arr) {

  messageTable(" ");

  let table = `
    <table border = 1 cellpadding = 10 >
    <th colspan=7 >Product Details</th>
    <tr>
      <th>sr No</th>
      <th>Product Id</th>
      <th>Part No</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  `;

  for (let item of arr) {
    console.log({arr})
    table += "<tr><td>" + item.key + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + item.id + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + item.partNo + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + item.productName + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + item.size + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + item.color + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + item.description + "</td>";
  } 

  messageTable(table);

}

function messageTable(data) {
  document.getElementById("messageTableA").innerHTML = data;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="sortByPartNo" onclick="sortByPartNo();">&nbsp;
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="messageTableA"></p>
```